# Curry function loosing object context

Tags: javascript, function, this, composition, currying

I'm trying to better understand context. I wrote a curry function that would transform any function into a curried one. My problem is when I try to apply the curry function to an object method, I loose the object's context.

```js
function curry(fun, ...args){
    if(args.length >= fun.length) return fun(...args)
    return (...rest) => curry(fun, ...args, ...rest)
}

const obj = {
    a: 'foo',
    b: function (a) { 
        return this.a + a; 
    }
} 

obj.foobar = curry(obj.b, 'bar');
console.log(obj.foobar) 
// return undefinedbar while should return foobar

const foobar = curry(obj.b)
console.log(foobar('bar'))
// return undefinedbar while should return foobar
```

Comment: You could [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) `this` (or whatever you want, e.g. pass the object you want and bind it.) to the function you return.

Comment: I understand that 
`
const curry = (funny, ...args) => {
    const fun = funny.bind(obj)
    if(args.length >= fun.length) return fun(...args)
    return (...rest) => curry(fun, ...args, ...rest)
}
`
would work in my example. But what if I want something generic, with "funny" possibly coming from diverse objects ? In other words, is there a way to retreive from which object a method comes from ?